# Dynamic web procject creation error with eclipse?

Tags: java, web-applications, ide

Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 3.0.

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.WebLogicServerInstall
```

Comment: installing ? can you elaborate

Comment: it seems like this is related to installing the OBEO UML Designer (eclipse 4.2)

Answer (score 1):

Install Eclipse Java EE Developer tools, Eclipse Java Web Developer tools, Java Server Faces tools, Eclipse faceted Project Framework, Eclipse faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement. You can install all these from Eclipse itself. Go to Help and install new software. It wont give the error again.

Answer (score 0):

The error in eclipse will go away if you reinstall the Weblogic Tools from the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) update site.